# Values of $a,b,c$ such that $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x(a+b-\cos x)-c\sin x}{x^5}=1$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, derivatives

Find the values of $a,b,c$ such that $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x(a+b-\cos x)-c\sin x}{x^5}=1$$

Here's what I have got so far

Using L'Hospital's rule,
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{a+b-\cos x+x\sin x-c\cos x}{5x^4}=1$$

So,$a+b-1=0$
Again,
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x+\sin x+x\cos x+c\sin x}{20x^3}=1$$

But the solution is given as $a=120,b=60,c=180$

There is no way that $a+b=1$

Comment: Your first step has a typo. You should get $c\cos x$ after differentiation

Comment: Probably easier to use power series. But are you sure you have the question right? Having both $a$ and $b$ seems superfluous.

Comment: And the proper and easy method to deal with such problems is Taylor series. Using L'Hospital's Rule requires justification at each step, because it is being used in reverse.

Comment: this seems like a very weird question, because $a+b$ could be substituted by some constant to be determined $k$ without loss.

Comment: The problem seems incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x(a+b-\cos x)-c\sin x}{x^5}=1$$ is given, we need
$$(x(a+b-\cos x)-c\sin x)'_{x=0}=0$$ or
$$(a+b-\cos{x}+x\sin{x}-c\cos{x})_{x=0}=0$$ or
$$a+b-c-1=0.$$ 
Thus, $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{a+b-(1+c)\cos{x}+x\sin{x}}{5x^4}=1.$$
Hence, we need $$(a+b-(1+c)\cos{x}+x\sin{x})'_{x=0}=0$$ or
$$((1+c)\sin{x}+\sin{x}+x\cos{x})_{x=0}=0,$$ which is true, which says
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(2+c)\sin{x}+x\cos{x}}{20x^3}=1$$ and from here
$$((2+c)\sin{x}+x\cos{x})'_{x=0}=0$$ or
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{(3+c)\cos{x}-x\sin{x}}{60x^2}=1,$$ where $c=-3$ and we get $-\frac{1}{60}=1$, which is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Expand with Taylor:
$$
x(a+b-\cos x)-c\sin x=
x\left(a+b-1+\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^4}{4!}\right)
-c\left(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}\right)+o(x^5)
$$
Thus you want
$$
\begin{cases}
a+b-1-c=0 \\[4px]
1/2+c/6=0 \\[4px]
-1/24-c/120=1
\end{cases}
$$
The second equation becomes $c=-3$, the third becomes $-5-c=120$.

No solution.